# "if statement" in python

Tags: python, if-statement, error-handling, conditional-statements

I have the code below (attach). What I want to do is to prompt a user to enter a ticker from Quandl website (financial/economic data) so that the dataset is retrieved. One condition, the data should be of 1-month length starting from the time when a user enters ticker.Let'say if the program is run on 22/01/2018 so the data should be from 22/12/2017 till 22/01/2018 (That is the first thing I am struggling with). Second, I want to make sure that the ticker is entered correctly, so I want to make a condition such that "if the command "quandl.get("ticker", start_date=trim_start, end_date=trim_end)" does not retrieve the data- re-enter the ticker" 
Please, advise me this issue.

```
'''Installation steps - go to "Command line" and pass "pip install quandl"'''
 import quandl                        #To extract the data from Quandl 
 website
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      #Plotting library
 import datetime
def MainFormula():
ticker = None 
while ticker is None:
    ticker = input("Please, enter stock ticker (should be available in Quandl Website): ")
    try:
        trim_end=datetime.datetime.now()
        trim_start= trim_end - 30
        if quandl.get("ticker", start_date=trim_start, end_date=trim_end) == True:
            print("Here are the results: ")             
        else:            
            print("Please, enter correct stock ticker (check Quandl website)! ")
    except ValueError as e1:
        print("Please, enter correct alpha (should be float - example: 0.2) ")                 

 program = MainFormula()               
 print(program)
```

Comment: Check out the `datetime` module for your first question. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part. You can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. Like this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_time = datetime.now()

one_month_ago = date_time - timedelta(weeks=4)

print('NOW: ', date_time)
print('ONE_MONTH_AGO: ', one_month_ago)
```

---

```
NOW:  2018-01-22 10:49:59.967355
ONE_MONTH_AGO:  2017-12-25 10:49:59.967355
```

I'm not familiar with the `quandle` API. I will have a very brief read of the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Quandl/) for **you**.

**UPDATE**

Here is how I experimented to try and solve your problem. You can see I just try to get something I know will fail. I import the correct exceptions and handle them in a `try` `except` block. I hope this helps.

```
>>> import quandl
>>> result = quandl.get('NOTHING')
Traceback (most recent call last):
SyntaxError: Invalid format used for Quandl database code.         The correct format is: `DATABASE_CODE/DATASET_CODE`
>>> result = quandl.get('GOOG/NYSE_IBM')
Traceback (most recent call last):
quandl.errors.quandl_error.NotFoundError: (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.
>>> from quandl.errors.quandl_error import NotFoundError
>>> def example_error_handling(*args, **kwargs):
...     try:
...         result = quandl.get(*args, **kwargs)
...     except (SyntaxError, NotFoundError):
...         print('INCORRECT ARGUMENTS. PLEASE TRY AGAIN')
...         # Should probably raise an exception here. Handle it better than a print!
...     else:
...         return result
...     
>>> result = example_error_handling('GOOG/NYSE_IBM')
INCORRECT ARGUMENTS. PLEASE TRY AGAIN
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used your statements and modified my code.